# AFNetworking 3 - objective c - send data without key

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-3

I have a web service that requires only a text value. I know the normal situation is send a dictionary (key,value). This time I have send only one value.
How can I send via POST only one value?

The value: `Hello "Ricardo","Carlos"`

Comment: How will server guy recognise that you have sent something without key?

Comment: Are you trying to send simple text? Not JSON or XML for instance? You could do `[myMutableURLRequest setHTTPBody:[myString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`, but that depend on your doc.

Comment: can u show your code for that?

Comment: @Mr.Bista I did the same with Android-retrofit. The server works fine.

Comment: PHP: `$_POST["some-key"]`, how does server guy fetches the value without key?

Comment: @Jack what code? I have not idea how send params without dictionary.

Comment: Have u write some code using afnetworking so please show it.

Comment: also show your URL format to send data.

Comment: Did you try my suggestion? But also, you may want to show some code.